# Get job title using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

I've successfully used the AccountManagement code to retrieve basic AD information but it's only returning a very limited set of information about the returned object. How can I get extended information from AD using the AccountManagement functionality. Specifically the Job Title or title as it seems to be called in my instance of AD.

I know how to do it using the older DirectoryServices but I'd like to know how to do it using the new namespace.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, the default set of properties on `UserPrincipal` is quite limited - but the great part is: there's a neat extensibility story in place!

You need to define a class descending from `UserPrincipal` and then you can very easily get access to a lot more properties, if needed.

The skeleton would look something like this:

```
namespace ADExtended
{
    [DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
    [DirectoryObjectClass("User")]
    public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
    {
        // Inplement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
        public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
        { }

        // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
        public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                             string samAccountName,
                             string password,
                             bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
        {} 

        UserPrincipalExSearchFilter searchFilter;

        new public UserPrincipalExSearchFilter AdvancedSearchFilter
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == searchFilter)
                    searchFilter = new UserPrincipalExSearchFilter(this);

                return searchFilter;
            }
        }

        // Create the "Title" property.    
        [DirectoryProperty("title")]
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                if (ExtensionGet("title").Length != 1)
                    return string.Empty;

                return (string)ExtensionGet("title")[0];
            }
            set { ExtensionSet("title", value); }
        }

        // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity.
        public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityValue);
        }

        // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity. 
        public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityType, identityValue);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's really almost all there is! The `ExtensionGet` and `ExtensionSet` methods allow you to "reach down" into the underlying directory entry and grab out all the attributes you might be interested in....

Now, in your code, use your new `UserPrincipalEx` class instead of `UserPrincipal`:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // Search the directory for the new object. 
    UserPrincipalEx myUser = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, "someUserName");

    if(myUser != null)
    { 
        // get the title which is now available on your "myUser" object!
        string title = myUser.Title;
    }
}
```

Read all about the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and its extensibility story here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

**Update:** sorry - here's the `UserPrincipalExSearchFilter` class - missed that one in the original post. It just shows the ability to also extend the search filters, if need be:

```
public class UserPrincipalExSearchFilter : AdvancedFilters
{
    public UserPrincipalExSearchFilter(Principal p) : base(p) { }

    public void LogonCount(int value, MatchType mt)
    {
        this.AdvancedFilterSet("LogonCount", value, typeof(int), mt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this type (UserPrincipalExSearchFilter) come from? Do I need to create this type using the pattern above? I actually pulled those few lines of code out and it seems to work perfectly (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @Jay: sorry - my bad - forgot to include this. Updated my response.

Comment: @ marc_s. Thankyou for pointing out the extensibility point (the ExtensionGet/Set protected methods), I guess it pays to look closer to home sometimes!!) Anyway, are you aware of security issues/config needed, to use the derived prinicpal object.  I have immplemented the sub class above and get an exception reading "Principal objects of type UserPrincpalEx can not be used to query this store". Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I had pulled across the code but had somehow removed the attributes at the top.  Without this decoration FindByIdentity throws a wobbler. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user with the UserPrincipalEx class? I receive errors saying "The server was unwilling to process the request". Other functionality seems to work great like updating department or employeeID.

Comment: @Force -- I was getting that same error until I changed the `DirectoryObjectClass` from "Person" to "User".  (hopefully you figured this out a year ago)

Comment: That was the exact issue that I was having as well. I completely forgot to return and post an update. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To Augment the above I have knocked up an extension method to call ExtensionGet.  It uses reflection to get hold of the protected method you would otherwise have to inherit.  You might need to use this if you are returning UserPrincipalObjects from Groups.Members, for example

```
public static class AccountManagmentExtensions
{
    public static string ExtensionGet(this UserPrincipal up, string key)
    {
        string value = null;
        MethodInfo mi = up.GetType()
            .GetMethod("ExtensionGet", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        Func<UserPrincipal, string, object[]> extensionGet = (k,v) => 
            ((object[])mi.Invoke(k, new object[] { v }));

        if (extensionGet(up,key).Length > 0)
        {
            value = (string)extensionGet(up, key)[0]; 
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is pretty handy trick. i was like "oh now i need to subclass!" You're just going around the fact that the method is protected and designed to be accessed through a subclass. Reminds me of a topic I wrote about how you can use .NET reflection to "breach" OOP concepts: http://mazdev.blogspot.ae/2011/05/breaching-object-oriented-programming.html

Comment: What is the value of the key is not a string value. like `System._comObject` in `accountExpires` property.

Answer (score 3):

There are simpler ways of getting to that info. Here is the way I got to Job Title in VB.NET:

```
Dim yourDomain As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourcompany.local")
Dim user1 As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, principal.Identity.Name)
Dim Entry As DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = user1.GetUnderlyingObject()

Dim JobTitle As String = Entry.Properties.Item("Title").Value.ToString
```

Comment: Works. System.DirectoryServices must be referenced. C# way: `(ldapEntry.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry)?.Properties["Title"].Value ?? "EMPTY"`

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Programmierus' comment, here is a simple way to do this on the fly in C#.

```
    public static string GetProperty(UserPrincipal userPrincipal, string property)
    {
        DirectoryEntry d = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
        return d.Properties[property]?.Value?.ToString();
    }
```