# Get active directory user attributes in Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, userprincipal

I have a code which is getting users from a specific group.

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
        GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupName);

        if (grp != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that i am not able to get users Mobile phone, Home phone, Department, Country. Has someone any ideas how it can be done using this method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ExtensionGet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.extensionget) method in @HuroSwords answer cannot be used directly as it is a protected method.

As is mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540436/get-job-title-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement) you'll need to create your own child class to use it.  I've included a sample of what I've done in the past to get extra user attributes below.

```cs
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("User")]
public class UserPrincipalExtended : UserPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipalExtended(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity to return my extended type
    public static new UserPrincipalExtended FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalExtended)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalExtended), identityValue);
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity to return my extended type
    public static new UserPrincipalExtended FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalExtended)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalExtended), identityType, identityValue);
    }

    [DirectoryProperty("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")]
    public string Department
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").Length != 1)
                return null;
            return (string)ExtensionGet("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the child class like you would a normal UserPrincipal object.

```
var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipalExtended.FindByIdentity(domain, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
Console.WriteLine(userPrincipal.Location);
```

In your case you may need to re-fetch the principal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare `UserPrincipal` instead `Principal` in your `foreach` loop to allow you use the properties specifically defined for Active Directory Users.

Or you can try to include this code on your loop.

```
Console.WriteLine(p.ExtensionGet("mobile")); // Mobile Phone
Console.WriteLine(p.ExtensionGet("homePhone"));  // Home Phone
Console.WriteLine(p.ExtensionGet("department"));  // Department
Console.WriteLine(p.ExtensionGet("co")); // Country
```

The method `ExtensionGet` allows you, not only retrieve data from standard Active Directory fields, rather than other customized data included on your catalog.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i do not have ExtensionGet

Comment: Are you targeting your project to .NET 4.5, isn't it? There is a `ExtensionGet` method on `Principal` class ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.extensionget(v=vs.110).aspx))