# Writing thumbnailPhoto property to Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm creating an application (.Net 3.5) to allow users to update their own photos and telephone numbers in Active Directory.

I'm using the UserPrincipal class, which I've extended using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540436/get-job-title-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement)

```
    // Create the "thumbnailPhoto" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("thumbnailPhoto")]
    public byte[] thumbnailPhoto
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("thumbnailPhoto").Length != 1)
                return null;

            return (byte[])ExtensionGet("thumbnailPhoto")[0];
        }
        set
        {
            ExtensionSet("thumbnailPhoto", value);
        }
    }
```

I get the byte array and write it to a pictureBox with

```
pictureBoxthumbnail.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(userPrincipal.thumbnailPhoto));
```

This shows the picture, on the form, so far so good. When I try to write the image to Active Directory, I convert the pictureBox to a byte array with

```
userPrincipal.thumbnailPhoto = ImageManipulation.imageToByteArray(pictureBoxthumbnail.Image);

public static byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

And try and save the data, but I get the following exception.

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException was unhandled
>
> Message=Unspecified error
>
> Source=System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
>
> ErrorCode=-2147467259

I suspect my pictureBox to byte array is wrong. Is anyone able to help?

Thank you.

Comment: -2147467259 = `0x80004005` = Access Denied - sure you have the rights to set that attribute?

Comment: I can clear the thumbnail. And using ADPhotoEdit as myself, I can upload a new photo. Could be a permission problem though.

Comment: I don't think that as permission problem. I would like you to debug it and ensure and let us know for which line you are getting this error. I had written same type of application earlier and got that very error code when tried to enclose code in **using** for *MemoryStream*.

Comment: It happens when the information is saved to AD. After I set a new value for userPrincipal.thumbnailPhoto, I then call userPrincipal.Save(), which is when the exception occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get this working today using the function below. Hopefully this helps someone else.

```
    private void UpdatePhoto()
    {
        var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(principalContext, System.Environment.UserName);

        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}:389/{1}", principalContext.ConnectedServer, userPrincipal.DistinguishedName));
        directoryEntry.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value = ImageManipulation.imageToByteArray(pictureBoxthumbnail.Image);
        directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
```