# Extended UserPrincipal Only Returning an Empty String

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I was trying to find a way to get some of the attributes from an active directory user that aren't in the `UserPrincipal` object by default.  While searching for my answer I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540436/get-job-title-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement).  I'm sure the answer posted by @marc_s is right, it at least is very useful.  Because of it's usefulness I have created a `UserPrincipalEx` class and done everything like @marc_s suggested in his answer.  The class itself seems to be defined properly aside from that fact that my extended attribute, in this case `title` is always returning an empty string.  I double checked in AD that the attribute is called `title` so I should be grabbing the right attribute I'm just not getting any content for it.

@marc_s also mentions that the class is a *skeleton* but if that's why I can't get it to work what more would I need to add?

I defined his two classes in their own `.cs` class called `UserPrincipalEx.cs` and I have both the `UserPrincipalExSearchFilter` and `UserPrincipalEx` classes defined in that file.  When I create my object in my code however it always returns an empty string.

```
UserPrincipalEx user = new UserPrincipalEx(principal.Context);
if (user == null) return false;
return user.Title == "A value other than empty" | (user.Title == "" || user.Title == null);
```

What more do I need to do to grab the value of `title` from AD?

**Update:**

If I follow the retrieving of the `title` attribute the `UserPrincipalEx` always says it's null, which continues to make me feel like I did something wrong with `UserPrincipalEx.cs`

```
[DirectoryProperty("title")]
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        if (ExtensionGet("title").Length != 1)
            return string.Empty;

        return (string)ExtensionGet("title")[0];
    }
    set { ExtensionSet("title", value); }
}
```

It always hits the `return string.Empty;` and like the lines says, returns an empty string

**Update 2:**

From what I can tell it doesn't matter what extended attribute you're looking for UserPrincipalEx will always return a null and make the string empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the extended `UserPrincipal` I ended up just using a `DictionaryEntry` to find the value and compare it instead like so.

```
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(principal.Context);
if (user == null) return false;
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
string title = "";
if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("title"))
{
    title = directoryEntry.Properties["title"].Value.ToString();
}
return title == "Comparison Value" | (title == "" || title == null);
```